# Connection between class number and the theory of Ideals/Quadratic Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, reference-request, quadratic-forms

I've been studying the classic results in integer binary quadratic forms, mainly the equivalence and reduction of quadratic forms and the class number $H(d)$ (the definition I got for $H(d)$ is the number of equivalence classes of binary quadratic forms of discriminant $d$, for a non perfect square $d$), and I was wondering if someone could explain or give me a good reference for the connection between this function $H$ and the theory of ideals, quadratic fields and modern algebra.

Thank you.

Comment: D.A.Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms. For positive forms, class numbers equal, for indefinite forms there is the concept of narrow class group, the short version is that some form $f$ may not be equivalent to $-f.$